HikCentral Professional OpenAPI Authentication and JSON data fetch issue
I have been trying to call the parkingfee/calculate API using cURL PHP and I am able to get the 200 status code which means it reaches the server. But somehow the JSON data is not showing up even though I get the 200 status code. I have concluded it's an authentication issue but I couldn't really figure out where I went wrong.
I have contacted the tech support from hikvision but they would not help in that term and kept on suggesting for me to use CSHCSDKDemo application that comes with the HCP download. It seems they couldn't understand my request. The image I attached is the error I have been getting and it shows the status code 200 as well. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.
At first, I kept getting errors like HTTP failed request: 400 status code but when I changed the headers parameters, I finally got the 200 status code which means successfully called the API but the JSON data that comes with it does not show up. And also, in the documentation, it mentioned that I need to calculate the signature using So I am not sure where I went wrong.
The documentation link for this API is:
https://pinfo.hikvision.com/hkwsen/unzip/20240201150721_74009_doc/
The API URL format is: https://[serverAddress]:[serverPort]/artemis/api/vehicle/v1/parkingfee/calculate
Below is the instructions on how to calculate the signature:
Signature Calculation

Calculate the signature string by HmacSHA256 algorithm with the appKey or appSecret to
generate message digest.
Calculate the message digest by BASE64 algorithm to generate the signature.

Below is the complete code:
<?php
$apiUrl = 'https://127.0.0.1:443/artemis/api/vehicle/v1/parkingfee/calculate'; // Replace with actual endpoint
$urlEndpoint = '/api/vehicle/v1/parkingfee/calculate';
$httpMethod = 'POST';
$accept = 'application/json'; 
$acceptEncoding = 'gzip, deflate, sdch';
$acceptLanguage = 'en-US,en;q=0.8';
$connection = 'keep-alive';
$contentType = 'application/json;charset=UTF-8';
$x_requested_with = 'XMLHttpRequest';
$server = '-';
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$transferEncoding = 'chunked';
$x_application_context = '';
$plateLicense = '';
$userAgent = 'Chrome/61.0.3163.100';

$apiKey = '';
$apiSecret = '';

/*******************************************************       CONTENT-MD5         ************************************************************************** */

$requestBody = '';
if(isset($_POST['submitform'])){
    $apiKey = $_POST['apikey'];
    $apiSecret = $_POST['apisecret'];
    $apiUrl = $_POST['apiurl'];
    $requestBody = $_POST['jsonbody'];
}
// $requestBody =  array(
//     'userId' => 'admin',
//     //'plateLicense' => 'UKM9999');
//     'plateLicense' => $plateLicense);
    
$jsonRequestBody = json_encode($requestBody, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$contentMD5 = base64_encode(md5($jsonRequestBody, true));
$contentLength = strlen($requestBody);

/*******************************************************     RESPONSE BODY         ************************************************************************** */
//response body format
$responseBody = array(
    'code' => 0,
    'msg' => 'Success',
    'data' => array(
        'plateLicense' => 'UKM9999',
        'cardNum' => '',
        'parkingInTime' => '2024-06-13T14:22:01+08:00',
        'parkingDuration' => 437809,
        'feeRuleType' => 0,
        'feeRuleIndexCode' => '1',
        'feeRuleName' => 'test rule',
        'fee' => '00.00'));

//encode the above in json format
$jsonResponseBody = json_encode($responseBody, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonResponseBody, true);
/*******************************************************       UUID/X-CA-NONCE         *********************************************************************** */
function generateUUID() {
    $data = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    assert(strlen($data) === 16);

    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40); // Set version to 0100
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80); // Set bits 6-7 to 10

    return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
}
$x_ca_nonce = generateUUID();
/*******************************************************        TIMESTAMP         ************************************************************************** */
$dateString = strtotime("Y-M-D h:i:sa"); 
$dateTime = new DateTime($dateString); 
$timestampInSeconds = $dateTime->getTimestamp(); 
$timestampInMilliseconds = $timestampInSeconds * 1000; 
$timestampInMilliseconds2 = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

// Initialize cURL session
$ch = curl_init();

/*******************************************************       SIGNATURE CALCULATION         ***************************************************************** */
$stringToSign = "{$httpMethod}\n". "{$contentMD5}\n". "{$contentType}\n". "{$apiKey}\n". "{$x_ca_nonce}\n". "{$timestampInMilliseconds}\n". "{$urlEndpoint}";

// Generate Signature
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $stringToSign, $apiSecret, true);
// Encode Signature (base64)
$base64encodedSignature = base64_encode($signature);
/*******************************************************       CURL SETOPT         ************************************************************************** */

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, 'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //set request method to post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46V2VtYWwzMjEh', // Adjust according to API's authentication requirements
    'Accept: '. $accept.'*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding: '. $acceptEncoding,
    'Accept-Language: '. $acceptLanguage,
    'Connection: '. $connection,
    'Content-Length: '. $contentLength, 
    'Content-MD5: '. $contentMD5,
    'Content-Type: '. $contentType,
    'Host: '. $host,
    'Server: '. $server,
    'transferEncoding: '. $transferEncoding, //cant make it like others, will display 400 error again, like Transfer-Encoding
    'X-CA-Key: ' . $apiKey,
    'X-CA-Signature: ' . $base64encodedSignature,
    'X-CA-Signature-Headers: X-CA-Key, X-CA-Timestamp',
    'X-CA-Timestamp: ' . $timestampInMilliseconds,
    'X-CA-Nonce: ' . $x_ca_nonce,
    'userId: admin', 
    'X-Requested-With: '. $x_requested_with
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);

// Execute the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Close the cURL session
curl_close($ch);
?>

<!-- Form Request API -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Test HikVision API</title>
    <style>
        body {
            color:rgb(220, 241, 208);
            background-color: rgb(44, 42, 62);
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            /*height: 100vh;*/
            margin-top: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 80px;
        }
        .container2 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .container3 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            /* align-items: center; */
            /*height: 100vh;*/
            margin-top: 50px;
            margin-bottom: 80px;
        }
        .textlarge {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hikvision Open API Test&emsp;</h1>
        <div class="container2">
            <form name="submitrequest" action="" method="post">
                <label for="APPKey">APP Key: </label><br>
                <input required type="text" name="apikey" placeholder="APP key"><br><br>
                <label for="APPSecret">APP Secret: </label><br>
                <input required type="text" name="apisecret" placeholder="APP secret"><br><br>
                <label for="APIurl">API: </label><br>
                <input required type="text" name="apiurl" placeholder="URL"><br><br>
                <label for="Body">Body: </label><br>
                <input type="text" class="textlarge" name="jsonbody"placeholder="Request Body"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitform">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container3">
        <h1>Results</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container3">
        <?php
        // Check for errors
        if(isset($_POST['submitform'])){
            if ($response === false) {
                echo 'cURL error: ' . curl_error($ch);
            } else {
                // Decode the JSON response
                $responseData = json_decode($response, false, 512, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                // $responseData = json_decode($response, true);
                // echo $responseData;
                // encoded response
                echo "Encoded response body: " . $response . "<br><br><br>";
                echo "Decoded response body: ";
                if($responseData === NULL) echo "No decoded JSON response. <br><br><br>";
                else echo $responseData . "<br><br><br>"; 
                $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                if ($resultStatus == 200) {
                    // everything went better than expected
                echo "Status Code: ".$resultStatus."<br><br><br>"; 
                print_r($responseData);
                } else {
                    // the request did not complete as expected. common errors are 4xx
                    // (not found, bad request, etc.) and 5xx (usually concerning
                    // errors/exceptions in the remote script execution)
                    die('Request failed: HTTP status code: ' . $resultStatus);
                }
                // Process the response data
                if ($responseData === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
                    // echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
                    echo "Error decoding JSON response: " . json_last_error_msg();
                } elseif ($responseData === null) {
                    echo "The response body is empty!";
                } else {
                    // Everything went as expected
                    echo "HTTP status code: $resultStatus\n";
                    print_r($responseData);
                }
                // print_r($_POST);
                //example if want json to print pretty
                // echo json_encode($this->errors, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

I am expecting it to give a JSON response like this:
{
    "code": "0",
    "msg": "Success",
    "data": {
        "plateLicense": "UKM9999",
        "cardNum": "",
        "parkingInTime": "2024-06-13T14:22:01+08:00",
        "parkingDuration": 2223046,
        "feeRuleType": 0,
        "feeRuleIndexCode": "1",
        "feeRuleName": "test rule",
        "fee": "260.00"
    }
}

I am not sure if the error comes from the signature calculation or the header. But the error I'm getting shows:

Status Code: 200 Error decoding JSON response: Control character
error, possibly incorrectly encoded

UPDATE:
I have attached an image to this post and edited the curl request and added the complete code. Error of the API call

"But the error I'm getting shows: Status Code: 200 Error decoding JSON response: Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded" - is that a response you are getting from the API? Or is it coming from your system, when it tries to decode the API response as JSON, but fails?

"but the JSON data that comes with it does not show up" - what does this mean?  The curl code you've shown is incomplete, it does not actually make the request.  Where's the rest, and how do you read the response?  And what do you do with the response?

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false - whilst false might work, as it resolves to zero, it is not recommended as you negate the security you are hoping to use.

You said there's an image attached showing the error message in context, but there's no image. Please [edit] your question.

From the documentation, I can see the API expects you to send a request body like this: {    "plateLicense" : "2700H" } . But your cURL code doesn't contain anything which would send JSON data to the server. So I'd guess the server is complaining that you haven't sent it any JSON, which is why it has an error when it tries to decode the request body as JSON. Not sure how you concluded that this related to authentication...you simply haven't sent it any data to process!

It also expects you to send a header called userId, but you don't seem to have done that either, looking at your list of headers. And I've no idea why you've put headers called url and method containing the URL and method you're trying to call. In a HTTP request the server already knows the URL you're requesting, because you requested it!! Putting it in a header as well is totally redundant. Looking at the protocol summary and signature documentation you also seem to sending other unnecessary headers - and I really strongly doubt you should be sending your secret key in the header!!

There seems to be a lot of guesswork going on here, whereas you need to pay much closer attention to the documentation and examples.

I forgot to add the last cURL request, which is to pass the JSON data. I have edited the post. @ADyson I included the userId in the header, but it still gave the same error.

The output shown in your screenshot looks like binary data, right?  So maybe the response is compressed?  So maybe somethnig wrong with the encoding you've specified?  You have $acceptEncoding = 'gzip, deflate, sdch'; - where did that come from?  I've never heard of sdch but this question suggests it was dead 8 years ago.  The PHP manual does not list is as an acceptable option either.  So maybe you're getting a response in an encoding format curl can't decode.

Unless the docs specified you should include that header, why not keep it simple?  From the manual: "If an empty string, "", is set, a header containing all supported encoding types is sent.". Or just omit the header?  Where did you get this sample code?

Thanks for the update. First observation: The whole section involving $responseBody seems to be redundant, because you never use it, and that's just a sample response. It's irrelevant to anything you're trying to do.

Second (more relevant) observation: $requestBody is taken from $_POST["jsonBody"];. What exactly does that field contain when you submit the HTML form? (It comes from the input field name="jsonbody" obviously.). If you are writing JSON text into that input, then you don't need to do $jsonRequestBody = json_encode($requestBody, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);, because the request body is already JSON. Re-encoding it will produce a different result, which in turn would mean that $contentMD5 and $contentLength are wrong compared to what you are actually sending in the curl request.

... and this in turn could throw off the hmac signature calculation.

Thirdly, the documentation image as shown here: https://pinfo.hikvision.com/hkwsen/unzip/20240201150721_74009_doc/GUID-AC658D35-B0C4-4ED0-A979-F1AC4028ED6A-high.png suggests the minimum set of HTTP headers you should sent in the request. I suggest 1) not using json_encode on the POST data, and 2) sending only those minimal headers (plus the userId header required by the specific endpoint you're calling). With those two changes, let's if you get a better result

I already found the solution. Thank you everyone! In the code, I have removed unnecessary headers and only kept Connection, Accept, Content-Type, App Key and the signature. And I also fixed the signature calculation, thanks to a friend I found in Reddit. As well as the request body format by passing the queried plateLicense in the text box as arrays then encode it as json format.

That's great. You should write it as an Answer below, with the corrected code, then if anyone else in future has a similar problem with this API they can get an instant solution. And you can get reputation points for it. See also [answer]

I already found the solutions to my problem. First, I removed unnecessary headers and only kept Connection, Accept, Content-Type, App Key and the signature as the headers in the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER. Then, I fixed my signature calculation. I also pass the queried plateLicense in the text box as arrays then encode it to JSON instead of passing the whole JSON body (which could work too but for the sake of testing, I prefer to pass it as array). The codes below are what I had changed in the PHP file:
//Header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Connection: '. $connection,
    'Accept: '. $accept,
    'Content-Type: '. $contentType,
    'X-Ca-Key: '. $apiKey,
    'X-Ca-Signature: '. $signature
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonRequestBody);

//Signature calculation
function generateHmacSha256Signature($jsonRequestBody, $apiSecret) {
    return hash_hmac('sha256', $jsonRequestBody, $apiSecret, true);
}

Hope this answer could help anyone facing the same problem!
